# Generating table from json in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to generate HTML table from json in AngularJS.
I receive JSON in format like this:
[image]

My Service for getting the data looks like this :

```
customAPI.getUsers = function() {
            return $http({
                method: 'JSONP',
                url: 'http://arka.foi.hr/WebDiP/2013_projekti/WebDiP2013_069/api/admin/users.php'
            });
        };
```

and controller for that code looks like this

```
controller('usersController', function($scope, customAPIservice) {
        $scope.filterName = null;
        $scope.usersList = [];

        /*Search*/
        $scope.searchFilter = function(user) {
            var keyword = new RegExp($scope.filterName, 'i');
            return !$scope.filterName || keyword.test(user.korisnici.korisnik_ime) || keyword.test(user.korisnici.korisnik_prezime);
        };

        customAPIservice.getUsers().success(function(response) {
            $scope.usersList = response.korisnici;
        });
    });
```

and my view looks like this :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="nameFilter" placeholder="Trazi..."/>
<h2 >Korisnici</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="6">Korisnici sustava</th>
        </tr>

    <th>Surname</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in usersList| filter: searchFilter">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>


        <td>{{user.korisnik.korisnik_prezime}}</td>
        <td>{{user.korisnik.korisnik_username}}</td>
    </tr>


    <tr  ng-show="usersList == ''">
        <td colspan="5">
            <img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

I think I messed up somewhere with binding the data with the view but I' still pretty new with angular so I can't find what is wrong. Also I've looked up over internet and couldn't find anything.Please help.

Comment: In your controller you have `customAPIservice` but your service is defined as `customAPI`

Comment: Yeah I know but this is just one part of the service js so this stuff works because I recieve JSON response, making table out of it is a problem

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly access the properties in your data.  Use:

`/*Search*/
        $scope.searchFilter = function(user) {
            var keyword = new RegExp($scope.filterName, 'i');
            return !$scope.filterName || keyword.test(user.korisnik.korisnik_ime) || keyword.test(user.korisnik.korisnik_prezime);
        };`

Comment: probably You're right but I can't test it properly because I can't generate table :/

Comment: Add Batarang so you can see what data is being loaded? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk

Comment: I did and It says that scope is empty,problem is somewhere here:

customAPIservice.getUsers().success(function(response) {
            $scope.usersList = response.korisnici;
        });

and ng-repeat. It seems like I don't add any data to scope.

Comment: If you want to create a plunkr I could look at that